Запуск команды в терминале при открытии проекта в VS Code
Прошу подсказать как можно сделать такую логику
Открываем проект в VS Code у меня там лежит файл docker-compose.yml
После открытия мне нужно выполнить ряд команд в терминале.
Возможно ли автоматизировать это процесс, т.е. как npm можно запускать скрипты?

Можете попробовать использовать & для параллельного запуска двух команд:
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/
